# One to zero-one relationship doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlite

My entities are like below:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    [ForeignKey("Class1")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Class1 Class1{ get; set; }
}
```

I need a **one to zero-one** relationship between this two entites in SQLite-Code-First. So I have used the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Class2)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Class1);
```

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I should not be able to insert an Id in `Class2` table if it's equivalent has not inserted in `Class1` already, but I can. Can anybody help me please?

If I change the naming of `Class2's Id` to something else, e.g. `Class1Id` like this:

```
public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Class1")]
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }
    public int? X { get; set; }
    public int? Y { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Class1_Class2_Target' in
>   relationship 'Class1_Class2'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check  what is the "Id" value of Class2 that you mentioned inserted successfully? Is it really referencing Class1 to begin with?

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 I have tried by custom inserting data in the SQLite DB.

Comment: If that is the case, it might be that the Class2's Id is the primary key of itself instead of being foreignKey pointing to Class1. Try changing the naming of Class2's Id to something else, e.g. Class1Id and give it a try.

Comment: as far as i rmb entity framework is sensitive to the keyword Id and will take it as the class' primary key unless being explicitly configured

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 I have tried with your suggestion as you can see in my updated question but I am getting the error as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is Sqlite. 
By default Sqlite doesn't support foreign keys despite the fact that you are using EF. 
You should explicity enable the support foreing keys.

1. Turn on the pragma: `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` You can execute this just like any other SQL statement. Note: You should execute it **for every new connection**.
2. Just change the connection string

   data source=C:\Dbs\myDb.db;foreign keys=true; (replace C:\Dbs\myDb.db with your sqlite database).

I prefer approach 2)

Comment: By using second approach it works fine in .NET now. But I still have problem when I try in the DB.